# c++ array and memory location

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a piece of code that deals with C++ array.

```
 using namespace std;
 #include <iostream>

 int main(){
 int *p;
 p = new int[3];
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    p[i] = i;
 }
 //delete[] p;
 for(int i = 0;i <3; i++){
    std::cout << *(p+i) << std::endl;
 }
}
```

How does this code work? How does the memory location *(p+i) work? How is it different from using p[i]. What are the differences on the code if we uncomment the line delete[] p.

Comment: `p+i` is `p` offset by `i` objects. `*(p+i)` is not different from `p[i]`. If you uncomment `delete[] p` you'll later access a released memory which is an UB.

Comment: @ihavenoidea - Of course I tried, but I need to know how it works. .

Comment: Where did you get the code from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) When you do this:

`p = new int[3];`

Now, `p` points to the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

When you do, `*(p + i)` will lead to simple pointer arithmetic. It will boil down to: `value of (<address pointed by p> + <size of type pointed by p> * i`) which is equivalent to doing `p[i]`.

That's why it works.

2) In C++, unlike java, you have to explicitly clear the dynamically allocated memory using `delete`, as there is no GC in C++ (and will never be, as per Bjarne Stroustrup). Otherwise, the memory area will remain acquired for the application lifetime, thereby causing memory leak.

*Suggestion:*

Place your `delete` at the end of the program. Otherwise, the loop below it may give SIGSEGV.

Also, Avoid using `new` and `delete` as much as you can.